# How to loop over table cells and display some result of distraction

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Look i have a table with two important parameters on every cell
My goal is to substract the 'rabat' parameters from 'produkty' parameter and then create a new one called result and make it be visible on the bottom of the cell

So far I made this but I have a problem to make loop.
I need to let It loop though all the cells of this type and show the result of this substraction.

Can you help me?

One more thing to say, I will use code injector extension to make it run on my application because I don't have access to change the code. Im not sure if its important.

```
//Produkty:
var step1 = document.querySelector("#orderTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)").innerHTML
var step2 = step1.slice(0, 17);
var step3 = step2.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var step4 = parseFloat(step3)

//Rabat:
var krok1 = step1.search("Rabat: ");
var krok2 = step1.slice(krok1 + 7, krok1 + 13 );
var krok3 = krok2.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var krok4 = parseFloat(krok3)

//Result:
var wynik = step4-krok4
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's your HTML?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Y9encJn

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem to change this code in your question into a loop?

Here you go:

```
// All Products:
var products = document.querySelectorAll("#orderTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)")
for (product of products) {
  //Produkty:
  var step1 = product.innerHTML
  var step2 = step1.slice(0, 17);
  var step3 = step2.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
  var step4 = parseFloat(step3)

  //Rabat:
  var krok1 = step1.search("Rabat: ");
  var krok2 = step1.slice(krok1 + 7, krok1 + 13 );
  var krok3 = krok2.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
  var krok4 = parseFloat(krok3)

  //Result:
  var wynik = step4-krok4
  // output your result to the HTML here
}
```

Comment: Mate @yunzen, can you help me with outputing the result in the cells? I tried all I though about and im stuck, look what I have but it doesnt work.

  //Result:
  var wynik = step4-krok4;
  products.innerHTML = products.innerHTML + '<p> <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(eval('wynik')) </script> </p>');